# developing hd wallet using bip32 and bip 39

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, bip32-hd-wallets, ethereum, c#

I'm developing a HD wallet using C#.
I want to use this wallet for multiple blockchains like bitcoin, ethereum, dogecoin etc...
I've read that I should use bip32 for my wallet. i know what's bip32 but couldn't find any effective way to use it.
can anyone help me with that?
thank you

Comment: What have you [looked for](https://www.google.com/search?q=bip32+library+c%23)? What found? What exact problems with implementing which part? Have you used stackoverflow for other C# programming problems? Can you clarify what an answer here would look like?

Comment: See: BIP 32 / 39 / 44 / 49 / 84. Note that questions related to cryptocurrencies other than bitcoin are off topic here.

Answer (score 0):

> i know what's bip32 but couldn't find any effective way to use it. can anyone help me with that? thank you

Use [NBitcoin](https://github.com/MetacoSA/NBitcoin) or [NBXplorer](https://github.com/dgarage/NBXplorer/)

There are no better libraries for C# developers in Bitcoin. These libraries also support some altcoins although questions related to altcoins are offtopic here.